# Calculating error in neural network back propagation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

This is a very simple question as I am new to the concepts.

I have a 4-4-1 neural network that I am running on 16x4 binary data to predict a 16x1 column of outputs.

I have utilized random weights and biases to generate a rough predicted output vector. I then calculate a vector of errors (actual-output) which is 16x1.

When back propagating, I am trying to update my weights. But how do I update the single value of a weight if my error is a 16x1 list of errors? That is, how do I implement:

weight = weight + learning_rate * error * input

if 'error' is 16x1 and input is 16x4?

Comment: To perform backpropagation you need a single scalar value as your error. If you have multiple error values then you usually add them together to get a single loss.